# add customer email in sales order grid magento

Tags: magento-1.7

how can i add customer email in admin html grid magento. i get customer email in collection but not displayed in column of Customer Email. Please Help me.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->join('order', 'main_table.entity_id = order.entity_id', 'customer_email');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
        $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
        'header' => $this->helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
        'index' => 'customer_email',
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('myorder'=>'sales_flat_order'),
        'myorder.entity_id = main_table.entity_id',
        array('myorder.customer_email')
    );
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

You need to add filter_index to code

```
$this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
    'header' => $this->helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
    'index' => 'customer_email',
    'filter_index' => 'myorder.customer_email',
));
```

Comment: Excellent. Just for others who are looking to do this, I had edited app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php - I'm not sure if this is the correct file, but it worked for me.

Comment: Actually, quick update, this will break your searches due to "ambiguous" rows being called... which means you will need to add the "filter_index" to each of your `addColumn` methods, using the "main_table.`column_name`" format.

Answer (score 1):

In `Grid.php`:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(
            'customer_entity',
            'main_table.customer_id = customer_entity.entity_id', array('customer_name' => 'email')
        );
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Then in `protected function _prepareColumns()` function add following code:

```
$this->addColumn('thumbnail', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Email'),
    'width'     => '100px',
    'index'     => 'customer_name',
    'type'        => 'text',
));
```

I think this [link](https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids) will solve your problem if you want to do more.

I know it was better to share the code, but the code is too much that's why I preferred to share the Link.

Comment: i get data when i update _prepareCollection like
protected function _prepareCollection()
   {
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
$this->setCollection($collection);
    $collection->join('order', 'main_table.entity_id = order.entity_id', 'customer_email');
return true;
}
but search functionality is not working of whole grid.

Comment: Try the way i shared

Comment: i want to add customer email column in grid and sorting ,filtering should be work properly.

Comment: The way i shared it is working, please share if there is any issue with the code i shared.